# If $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\sum_{x}xP(x|y)$ then why does $\mathbb{E}_{Y}[\mathbb{E}_{X}[X|Y]]=\sum_yp(y)\sum_xxp(x|y)$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

If $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\sum_{x}xP(x|y)$ then why does $\mathbb{E}_{Y}[\mathbb{E}_{X}[X|Y]]=\sum_yp(y)\sum_xxp(x|y)$?

I'm a little confused by notation I always assumed the subscripted variable for expectation denotes the variable value so $\mathbb{E}_{A}[RV]=a*(probability\_of\_a)$ and the term within the square brackets denotes the probability distribution. That seems somewhat consistent with the above as $\mathbb{E}_{X}[X|Y]=\sum_xxp(x|y)$, but then $\mathbb{E}_{Y}[RV]=\sum_yp(y)*expectation\_of\_RV$(RV = random variable), which is the opposite of what I thought was consistent as the subscripted variable $y$ has it's probability multiplied by the expected value of the random varaible.

Comment: For a random variable $RV$ which is a function of $A$, the formula for $\mathbb{E}_A[RV]$ is $\sum_a RV(a)p(a)$, not $\sum_a a p(a)$ (unless $RV$ is just $A$). For example, $\mathbb{E}_Y(\sin(Y)) = \sum_y \sin(y)p(y)$, not $\sum_y yp(y)$. 

Here we have $RV(y)=\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\sum_x x \mathbb{P}(x|Y)$, so $$\mathbb{E}_Y(RV) = \sum_y RV(y) p(y) = \sum_y p(y)RV(y) = \sum_y p(y)\Bigl[\sum_x xp(x|y)\Bigr]$$

Comment: @user469053 is this just standard notation? Is $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ a RV? I thought expected values are typically constants.

Comment: An expectation is a constant, but a conditional expectation is slightly different, in that it depends on the conditioning event, and as such it isn't (or, more precisely, it doesn't have to be) a constant. For example, assume Y is a random variable taking values in $(0,1)$, and X is a Bernoulli event (0 or 1 valued) which is 1 with probability Y. Then $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)=0\cdot (1-Y)+1\cdot Y=Y$, which is a function of $Y$, not a constant. Usually (but not always), the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ will depend on $Y$.

Comment: There can be subtle differences here. We could look at a conditional expectation (say, the expected value of $X$ given that $Y=.5$, for example), which *would* be a constant. But the notation $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ is the expectation of $X$ *given $Y$*, but not fixing a particular value of $Y$. The latter is a random variable, and after the fact you could plug in $Y$, for example, $Y=.5$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation